# Como carregar um ComboBox no Firemonkey para Android

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Tenho um Edit e ao lado um ComboBox. A ideia é que no edit exiba o id do registro e no combo a descrição. E ao alterar a opção no combo altere também o id no edit.

Na VCL da para inserir a descrição e o id assim:

`Combo.AddObject('descricao',TObject (id))`

Mas no Android isso retorna access violation por problemas de tipagem de dados.

Então minha pergunta é: como posso fazer isso no Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver meu problema de outra forma
Ao mesmo tempo que populo o combo com a descrição eu populo uma StringList com os ids.
No change do ComboBox Eu posiciono a StringList no mesmo Index.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
Combo.Items.AddObject('descricao', TObject(id));
```

Para recuperar o id do item selecionado no combo:

```
id := Integer(Combo.Items.Objects[Combo.ItemIndex]);
```

E para alterar o id no edit você pode atribuir um evento OnChange no Combo e atribuir o valor recuperado ao edit.

Comment: Não me lembro como chama o termo a(cho que é TypeCast), mas no Android isso não funciona, pois no TObject (id) você está passando um inteiro como objeto e o Android não aceita. Neste link está melhor explicado https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=105411

Comment: Certo, acabei não testando no Android.